# Is there any way for subtasks to inherit deadlines in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

It would be really convenient if for certain tasks in org-mode, the subtasks could inherit the deadline of the main task. This behavior should occur in case I have not already specified a deadline for the subtask. In this way, all the subtasks would show up in my org-agenda view, with proper deadlines which are easily manipulatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a function for adding subtasks? This one adds a deadline to the subtask if its parent has one:

```
(defun my-org-insert-sub-task ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((parent-deadline (org-get-deadline-time nil)))
    (org-goto-sibling)
    (org-insert-todo-subheading t)
    (when parent-deadline
      (org-deadline nil parent-deadline))))
```

Don't forget to bind it to a key:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c s") 'my-org-insert-sub-task)
```

Also you might find these settings useful:

```
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
```

Comment: :) a different way to approach the problem! I don't use a key-binding to add tasks, I simply add them by writing them down in the file. I don't know if I can break that habit when I try this, but I'll certainly give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If you can't find a way to solve a problem, invent a new problem you can solve! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's advice that works for recent versions of Org 9, unlike my previous answer which stopped working at some point.

```
(defun org-entry-properties-inherit-deadline (orig-fun &optional pom which)
  "Call ORIG-FUN with POM, but if WHICH is `DEADLINE' do it recursively."

  (if (string= which "DEADLINE")
      (org-with-point-at pom
        (let (value)
          (while (not (or (setq value (funcall orig-fun (point) which))
                          (not (org-up-heading-safe)))))
          value)
    (funcall orig-fun pom which))))
(advice-add 'org-entry-properties :around #'org-entry-properties-inherit-deadline)
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently, this question was asked and answered on the org-mode mailing list. I'm adding that discussion here in the hopes that someone will find it useful:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/49215

I've added that code into my .emacs in this commit:

https://github.com/vedang/emacs-config/commit/1cb6c774a991d50853134d8085ca61dd12585993

Comment: This looks great but doesn't seem to work for me, as `org-entry-get-with-inheritance` doesn't seem to be able to get special properties like DEADLINE...

Answer (score 1):

DEADLINE is one of these properties, that are not inherited by default. 
You can change that by customizing the variable `org-use-property-inheritance`

Comment: This does not work. I set the value of `org-use-property-inheritance` to `t`, and when that did not work I set it to `("DEADLINE")`. However the deadline property is not inherited (it does not reflect in my Org-Agenda).

Comment: You are right, items with an inherited DEADLINE property do not show up in the agenda. I don't know how to change that. But they do show up in a special TODO list, if you want. (You may try that in order to see, if the inheritance works.) Hit `M-x org-tags-view` and confine the search to something like `DEADLINE<="<2011-09-01>"`.

Answer (score 1):

Org-mode has the capability to inherit tags like deadlines, but by default `org-entry-get` does not do so. Here's advice to ensure that `DEADLINE` is always inherited.

```
(defvar inherit-override nil)
(defun org-entry-get-inherit-deadline (orig-fun pom property &optional inherit &rest args)
  "Call ORIG-FUN with POM, but if PROPERTY is `DEADLINE', set INHERIT.

Passes through remaining ARGS.

Sets inherit-override variable which stops infinite loops."
  (when (and (eq inherit nil)
             (string= property "DEADLINE")
             (not inherit-override))
    (setq inherit t))
  (let ((inherit-override t))
    (apply orig-fun pom property inherit args)))

(advice-add 'org-entry-get :around #'org-entry-get-inherit-deadline)
```

Comment: I think this worked through Org 8 but not for Org 9.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `org-agenda-bulk-action` in `org-agenda-mode`.

1. Define `stuck-projects` as TODO headings that do not yet have a deadline and have not yet been scheduled: [Defining unscheduled todos as stuck projects in Emacs Org-Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812520/defining-unscheduled-todos-as-stuck-projects-in-emacs-org-mode)
2. `M-x org-agenda-list-stuck-projects`. This will display a list of TODO headings with no deadline.
3. <kbd>m</kbd> to mark the entries to which you'd like to add a deadline.
4. <kbd>B</kbd> to invoke `org-agenda-bulk-action`.
5. <kbd>d</kbd> to assign a single deadline to all of them.