# Defining unscheduled todos as stuck projects in Emacs Org-Mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to setup the org-stuck-projects variable so that the "stuck projects" agenda will list all headlines which are TODOs (any TODO keyword except DONE) but those which don't have SCHEDULED or DEADLINE attributes set. Currently I get an empty list with this setting for the variable:

```
(setq org-stuck-projects
  '("TODO" nil nil "SCHEDULED:|DEADLINE:"))
```

I've checked to have some TODO'ed tasks with no scheduled date or deadline.

Comment: Ok, I've found the correct setting for this purpose: `'("TODO={.+}/-DONE" nil nil "SCHEDULED:\\|DEADLINE:"))`. Good luck.

Comment: I would suggest placing this as an answer to your own question, so that it appears as having answers, not simply as an edit (easier to look for an answer when it shows it has one) See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 11):

Found a solution:

```
'("TODO={.+}/-DONE" nil nil "SCHEDULED:\\|DEADLINE:"))
```

(thanks to user Jonathan Leech-Pepin for suggesting re-posting this as an answer instead of comment to the original post).