# Define org mode stuck projects as having no scheduled tasks

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am looking to define stuck projects as those that either have no TODOs, or, maybe they have TODO entries but none of them is scheduled.  My thinking on this is: I may build up a set of TODOs against a project, but if none of them is scheduled, it will never make it onto my agenda and get acted upon.  So from that standpoint just having a 'TODO' item doesn't do me any good unless something is scheduled (even if in the future).

I was originally using '*' to match any TODO state but then I tried replacing it with a regexp match on 'SCHEDULED: <.+>'.  At first this looked like it would suit my needs; however when I mark a task as Completed, the SCHEDULED property is still there so the project still appears 'unstuck' even if I have no other tasks defined yet, or tasks that aren't scheduled.

I came across this discussion: [Defining unscheduled todos as stuck projects in Emacs Org-Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812520/defining-unscheduled-todos-as-stuck-projects-in-emacs-org-mode) - but it looks to me like that setup would have the same problem.

I suppose I could keep removing the scheduled date as I complete things, but this seems cumbersome.  There also doesn't seem to be a way to do any kind of multi-line regexp on individual tasks.  Any ideas whether it's possible somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this would better be asked over at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/